# Differential equation with distributed coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-distributions

I was wondering how an ordinary differential equation $\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = b x(t)$ is called when $b$ is distributed, say $b \sim N(0,1)$. But I don't mean a randomly varying coefficient; just one that at starting time $t_0$ has a given distribution. If we start at some point $x(t_{0}) = x_{0}$, at some later point $t_{1}$ we should have a distribution of $x(t_{1})$ conditional on $b$, should we not?

A discrete version of this would be, say, three different coefficients $b_{1} < b_{2} < b_{3}$, such that for a given $x(t_{0})$ we'd than find different $x(t_{1})$ depending on $b$, i.e. $x(t_{1}|b_{1}) < x(t_{1}|b_{2}) < x(t_{1}|b_{3})$. What I'm looking for is the continuous version of that.

It appears to me at least that this should be a simple textbook problem, but since I don't know the name for these type of equations, I'm kinda stuck. I'd appreciate if somebody knew the correct name for this kind of equation, or (even better) could point me to some textbook treatments.

Comment: You're very close to stochastic differential equations, but studying them requires some measure theory and knowledge of Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: But isn't a SDE fluctuating at any instant between $t_0$ and $t_1$? What I thought of was more along the lines of "fast growing" vs. "slow growing" (but continuous).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're asking for the distribution of the random variable $x(t_1) = x(t_0) \, e^{b \, (t_1-t_0)}$ given that the random variable $b$ is $N(0,1)$, and for given numbers $t_0$, $x(t_0)$ and $t_1$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, although not necessarily $N(0,1)$. Just some distribution, but fixed at $t_0$ rather than randomly fluctuating.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't mean $b$ to be a random draw from some distribution, but actually the entire distribution itself.

Comment: @Durden this isn’t entirely clear from the question. You should just write that $b$ is the PDF of a normal RV, for example. The notation $b\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ in probability theory and statistics conventionally means that $b$ is a random sample drawn from the subsequent distribution.

Comment: I see. Let me recast the question: assume we had two coefficients, $b_1 < b_2$. We start at $x(t_0)$ for both, but then $dx(t)=b_2 x(t) dt$ will grow faster. At the end $x(t_1; b_2)$ will be larger than $x(t_1;b_1)$. My original question was: what if instead of $b_1$ and $b_2$, we had a continuous distribution of $b$. How are such equations called?

Answer (score 1):

(If I understood your last comment correctly)

They have different names, one of them: selection systems. You can check, for instance, [this paper](https://www.mmnp-journal.org/articles/mmnp/pdf/2014/03/mmnp201493p68.pdf).

Also, probably better to say that you are looking for the solution of the problem
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}(t,b)=b x(t,b)
$$
with the initial condition
$$
x(0,b)=p(b),
$$
where $p(b)$ follows given distribution. That is it not $b$ that is distributed according to some law, but $x(t,b)$, and your goal to find this distribution if you know $x(0,b)$.

(All the answers are given in the linked paper. E.g., if $x(0,b)\sim N(0,1)$ then $x(t,b)\sim N(t,1)$.)

Comment: I don't quite understand your last line. For one, shouldn't $x(0,b)$ be bivariate? And second, shouldn't (the distribution of) $x$ experience some "spread" between $t_0$ and $t_1$ given distributed coefficients? But it seems you're suggesting just a shift of the distribution from $N(0,1)$ to $N(t,1)$.

Comment: I do not quite understand your question. Why $x(0,b)$ should be bivariate? Think of $x(0,b)$ as the pdf of normal distribution with some normalization (the integral is not one necessarily)  As the time goes, the individuals with bigger $b$ will produce more descendants, and the distribution of course shifts. Read the paper I linked (the same authors actually published a whole book recently on the same subject), it shows all the details.

Comment: Just another remark: all these things have something to do with the principle of the maximum entropy. :)

Comment: Oh, you're right. I confused $x(0,b)$ and $p(\cdot)$. In my mind there's a bivariate distribution $p(x,b)|_{t=t_0}$ evolving to  $p(x,b)|_{t=t_1}$.